# How do you vertically align images in Craigslist ads?

Tags: craigslist

I know that Craigslist allows for limited HTML and CSS, but I can't figure out how to vertically align images.

I've tried the `vertical-align` style, `valign` attribute, floating and adding `padding`.

Comment: Could you maybe post the code you've tried or a link to the post if you put it up?

Comment: Isn't craigslist phasing out the in-text image function? I think they are moving toward the image uploading function:

"Externally-hosted images (IMG tag) will soon be disallowed in for-sale ads. Please use CL image upload. "

Comment: @ReubenL. From what I've read, this is only in the "For Sale" section. That message doesn't appear on the "Service Offered" postings

Comment: Get in your time machine and travel several hundred thousand years into the future when craigslist isn't coded by huge clowns, then use vertical-align: middle; as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via using `display: table-cell;` for your parent element.

[Click here to see example](http://jsfiddle.net/flatiron_school/bR8KM/)